# Overriding to_s in rails model... possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, polymorphism

I've got this model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :votes

    def to_s
        "hello?"
    end
end
```

and when I attempt to display a `Question` with `<%= @question %>`

I get this...

`#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x1042b2960>`

obviously I expect to get `hello?`

Comment: It is definitely possible, I just did it in rails console. What do you get when you call to_s directly? I'm curious why you want to override to_s. If it's for rendering, maybe you'd prefer to keep that logic localized to the view and view helpers exclusively. The default output may be helpful and/or expected in other contexts such as debugging or even interactions with rails itself.

Comment: Can you post your controller code where you populate @question. Also, you can eliminate the view from the picture by doing `render :text=>@question` in your action method bod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure `@question` is a Question? The `to_s` response you are getting makes me think otherwise.

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x1042b2960>
```

It looks like you have a ActiveRecord::Relation, not a Question.

Comment: After further looking into it I was using `Question.where()` which returns an array of questions, so I was dealing with an array...